# Python - How to store a username/password from input

Tags: python, authentication

I was wondering how to store a username and password from input, and put it into a sort of database that is on the same python file. I would want the username and password to only be saved for however long the file is open, and don't require any long term storage of the data, thanks in advance!

Comment: By "saved" should it be available outside of hte running program for other programs to read, or just internally to the program?

Comment: Only internally

Comment: "Internally" isn't really a technical term here. The terms you're looking for are "in-memory" for short-term and "persistent" for long-term

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty simple stuff so I'll just give you the short answer, but you should probably do some more research on this in the future, as well provide the code you've written.

```py
credentials = {}

def create():
    username = input('Username: ')
    password = input('Password: ')
    credentials[username] = password

def authenticate():
    username = input('Username: ')
    password = input('Password: ')
    return credentials[username] == password
```

Use create() to create users and authenticate() to log users in

Comment: Thanks, that'll do it, and I'll be sure to add code next time.